# C# Expression internal structure

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm trying to understand how **Expression** class work.

A simple example:

```
Expression<Func<string, bool>> exp = p => p.Contains("x");
```

Why am I not getting an error like "you cannot convert to Expression<Func<string, bool>> because it isn't delegate" ?

I tried to debug this code and VS moves me to this method

```
public static ParameterExpression Parameter(Type type, string name)
    {
        Validate(type, allowByRef: true);
        bool byref = type.IsByRef;
        if (byref)
        {
            type = type.GetElementType();
        }

        return ParameterExpression.Make(type, name, byref);
    }
```

Is it Microsoft magic? I didn't find any overrode converter or something else and who called **Parameter** method? Did they write some special code in the compiler to compile **Expression** class not as any other "standard" class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you may call it magic because the compiler will do a lot of lifting for you behind scenes. So let us see what happens with the simplest program. I just created a Console Application and added your code.

```
internal class Program {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        Expression<Func<string, bool>> exp = p => p.Contains("x");
    }
}
```

I compiled it and looked at the IL code. (you may skip this part if you like)

```
IL_0000: ldtoken      [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.String/*01000021*/
IL_0005: call         class [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Type/*01000014*/ [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Type/*01000014*/::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.RuntimeTypeHandle/*01000022*/)/*0A000014*/
IL_000a: ldstr        "p"
IL_000f: call         class [System.Core/*23000002*/]System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression/*0100001D*/ [System.Core/*23000002*/]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression/*0100002D*/::Parameter(class [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Type/*01000014*/, string)/*0A000040*/
IL_0014: stloc.0      // V_0
IL_0015: ldloc.0      // V_0
IL_0016: ldtoken      method instance bool [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.String/*01000021*/::Contains(string)/*0A000041*/
IL_001b: call         class [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Reflection.MethodBase/*0100002E*/ [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Reflection.MethodBase/*0100002E*/::GetMethodFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.RuntimeMethodHandle/*0100002F*/)/*0A000042*/
IL_0020: castclass    [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Reflection.MethodInfo/*01000017*/
IL_0025: ldc.i4.1
IL_0026: newarr       [System.Core/*23000002*/]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression/*0100002D*/
IL_002b: dup
IL_002c: ldc.i4.0
IL_002d: ldstr        "x"
IL_0032: ldtoken      [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.String/*01000021*/
IL_0037: call         class [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Type/*01000014*/ [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Type/*01000014*/::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.RuntimeTypeHandle/*01000022*/)/*0A000014*/
IL_003c: call         class [System.Core/*23000002*/]System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression/*01000030*/ [System.Core/*23000002*/]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression/*0100002D*/::Constant(object, class [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Type/*01000014*/)/*0A000043*/
IL_0041: stelem.ref
IL_0042: call         class [System.Core/*23000002*/]System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression/*01000031*/ [System.Core/*23000002*/]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression/*0100002D*/::Call(class [System.Core/*23000002*/]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression/*0100002D*/, class [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Reflection.MethodInfo/*01000017*/, class [System.Core/*23000002*/]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression/*0100002D*/[])/*0A000044*/
IL_0047: ldc.i4.1
IL_0048: newarr       [System.Core/*23000002*/]System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression/*0100001D*/
IL_004d: dup
IL_004e: ldc.i4.0
IL_004f: ldloc.0      // V_0
IL_0050: stelem.ref
IL_0051: call         class [System.Core/*23000002*/]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1/*01000032*/<!!0/*class [mscorlib*//*23000001*//*]System.Func`2*//*01000012*//*<string, bool>*/> [System.Core/*23000002*/]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression/*0100002D*/::Lambda<class [mscorlib/*23000001*/]System.Func`2/*01000012*/<string, bool>>(class [System.Core/*23000002*/]System.Linq.Expressions.Expression/*0100002D*/, class [System.Core/*23000002*/]System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression/*0100001D*/[])/*2B000002*/
IL_0056: pop
```

And this IL Code roughly translates as

```
// Define Expresin parameter p
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof (string), "p");
// Gets method handler for string.Contains method
// Plase note that __methodref can not be used in c# butit is valid in il code
var methodInfo = (MethodInfo) MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(__methodref (string.Contains));
// Constant string x added as paramter
var constantXString = new Expression[] {Expression.Constant("x", typeof (string))};
// Call given method on the the given parameter and make it into a lambda expression
Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(Expression.Call(parameterExpression, methodInfo, constantXString), parameterExpression);
```

It is the first line of the code where you can see that `public static ParameterExpression Parameter(Type type, string name)` is being called.

Comment: NB. I've written a [library](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString) which takes an expression tree and generates a string of the [factory method calls needed to produce the same expression tree](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString/wiki/Available-renderers#3-factory-methods).

Comment: @ZevSpitz NB you too. Let me have a look at it

Comment: @ZevSpitz pretty neat! me likey